# QT - QTreeView with different colors for subgroups of the QTreeView items

Tags: c++, qt

Does anybody know how to implement/realize a `QTreeView` with different colors for subgroups of the `QTreeView` items?
Something like:

[image: 1]

Does anybody has done something like that and could give me a link to an tutorial or how to, or sample code would also be good. Currently I have absolutely no idea how to build this.

I'm working with Qt 5.1.1 and using the `QTreeView` with the `QFileSystemModel` and the `QItemSelectionModel`.

I also thought of :
`m_TreeView->setStyleSheet(...)`
but this only sets the style for the whole `treeView` or only for the selected ones.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You could try to look at `QAbstractItemModel::data()` with `Qt::BackgroundRole` as a second argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Qt::BackgroundRole](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) which can be used to return a QColor to be used by the view to paint an index' background.

As you use an existing item model class (QFileSystemModel), it would be easiest to put a proxy model on top of the file system model just doing the colorization.

Using [QIdentityProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qidentityproxymodel.html):

```
class ColorizeProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColorizeProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0) : QIdentityProxyModel(parent) {}

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
        if (role != Qt::BackgroundRole) 
            return QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);

        ... find out color for index 
        return color;
    }
};
```

To use it:

```
QFileSystemModel *fsModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
ColorizeProxyModel *colorProxy = new ColorizeProxyModel(this);
colorProxy->setSourceModel(fsModel);
treeView->setModel(colorProxy);
```

If you need anything more fancy, (like special shapes etc.), you'd need your own item delegate with custom painting (see [QStyledItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html)).

Comment: Why do you have to write "explicit" excplicitely?

Comment: @user1767754: Here's an explanation what explicit is about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean